# android.widget.EditText cannot be cast to com.businesscard.View.EditTextWithTextListener

Tags: android

What i am working on is really a sample program. I have delete some useless code so that you guys can clearly see what's happening here.

```
public class CreateMyCardFragment extends FragmentActivity implements EditTextListener
{
    private EditTextWithTextListener cardPositionEdit = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_create_my_card);

        cardPositionEdit = (EditTextWithTextListener) findViewById(R.id.cardPositionEdit);
        cardPositionEdit.setOnEditTextListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void textChanged(int id)
    {
        switch (id)
        {
            case R.id.cardPositionEdit:
                newCard.setCardPositionShow(cardPositionEdit.getText().toString());
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

When my program get into this page, it just crashed with following error（log）

```
06-24 23:51:24.710: E/AndroidRuntime(6285): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-24 23:51:24.710: E/AndroidRuntime(6285): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.businesscard/com.businesscard.ui.CreateMyCardFragment}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.EditText cannot be cast to com.businesscard.View.EditTextWithTextListener
06-24 23:51:24.710: E/AndroidRuntime(6285):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2080)
06-24 23:51:24.710: E/AndroidRuntime(6285):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2105)
06-24 23:51:24.710: E/AndroidRuntime(6285):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:136)
06-24 23:51:24.710: E/AndroidRuntime(6285):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1201)
06-24 23:51:24.710: E/AndroidRuntime(6285):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-24 23:51:24.710: E/AndroidRuntime(6285):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-24 23:51:24.710: E/AndroidRuntime(6285):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4797)
06-24 23:51:24.710: E/AndroidRuntime(6285):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-24 23:51:24.710: E/AndroidRuntime(6285):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-24 23:51:24.710: E/AndroidRuntime(6285):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
06-24 23:51:24.710: E/AndroidRuntime(6285):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
06-24 23:51:24.710: E/AndroidRuntime(6285):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-24 23:51:24.710: E/AndroidRuntime(6285): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.EditText cannot be cast to com.businesscard.View.EditTextWithTextListener
06-24 23:51:24.710: E/AndroidRuntime(6285):     at com.businesscard.ui.CreateMyCardFragment.onCreate(CreateMyCardFragment.java:76)
06-24 23:51:24.710: E/AndroidRuntime(6285):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5065)
06-24 23:51:24.710: E/AndroidRuntime(6285):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
06-24 23:51:24.710: E/AndroidRuntime(6285):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2044)
06-24 23:51:24.710: E/AndroidRuntime(6285):     ... 11 more
06-24 23:54:26.445: E/Trace(6853): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
```

anyone knows what's happening?

The EditTextWithTextListener class is defined like this

```
public class EditTextWithTextListener extends EditText
{

    private EditTextListener myTextListener = null;

    public EditTextWithTextListener(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public EditTextWithTextListener(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public EditTextWithTextListener(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);

    }

    public void setOnEditTextListener(EditTextListener listener)
    {
        this.myTextListener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onTextChanged(CharSequence text, int start, int lengthBefore, int lengthAfter)
    {
        if (null != myTextListener)
            myTextListener.textChanged(this.getId());
        super.onTextChanged(text, start, lengthBefore, lengthAfter);
    }
}
```

anyone knows what's happening here? and why EditText can't be cast to it's subclass?
any help is welcome, thanks in advance.

Comment: How is your `R.id.cardPositionEdit` defined in XML? You've defined it as an `EditTextWithTextListener`?

Comment: Oh Yes,i didn't changed my XML, Thank you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have created a custom `View` make sure you define it as such in your XML.

In your `fragment_create_my_card.xml` you should be referencing your view like this:

```
<com.businesscard.View.EditTextWithTextListener
    android:id="@+id/cardPositionEdit"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="wrap_content" />
```

`EditText` can't be cast to its subclass because it doesn't know anything about this subclass.

`EditTextWithTextListener` is an `EditText` but `EditText` is not an `EditTextWithTextListener`.

Comment: It works as i changed the XML to what you said, thank you very much.

Comment: By the way, if i got a EditTextWithTextListener, it's ok to cast it to EditText?

Comment: Depends on what you need it for but yes if you want to operate on it as if it was a regular EditText.